# Merge dataframes while removing duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I cant get my head around Merge and joins.

I have an initial data frame, that looks like below:

```
 Car    Units Month
 BMW     800   Jan
 Lexus   150   Jan
 Audi    210   Feb
 Mustang 90    Mar
 Bentley 110   Feb
 Jaguar  90    Jan
```

I will successively get more dataframes to append to this initial df.

And I will have to append only those values which are unique in 'Car' column and also 'Month' column.

Let's say I got another dataframe to append:

```
Car   Units Month
BMW     130   Jan
Tata    150   Jan
Maruti  110   Mar
Audi    250   Mar
```

**Desired output:**
When I append 2nd dataframe to the first one, 'Tata', 'Maruti', 'Audi' should get appended. 'BMW' should not get appended.

The code I am using is:

```
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.DataFrame(
   {
      "Car": ['BMW', 'Lexus', 'Audi', 'Mustang', 'Bentley', 'Jaguar'],"Units": [800, 150, 210, 90, 110, 90], "Month": ['Jan','Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Feb', 'Jan']
   }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
   {
      "Car": ['BMW', 'Tata', 'Maruti', 'Audi'],"Units": [130, 150, 110, 250], "Month": ['Jan','Jan','Mar', 'Mar']
   }
)


df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Car', 'Month'], how="left", indicator=False)
```

But somehow it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "left" will only affect to using just the keys on the left for `['Car', 'Month']`.

One solution is to use `outer` to have all the combinations of `['Car', 'Month']` keys. I set the indicator to true the origin of the value and also the left to have no suffix so we can take advantage of this later:

```
joined=pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Car', 'Month'],
                how="outer", indicator=True, suffixes=["", "_y"])
>> joined

       Car  Units Month  Units_y      _merge
0      BMW  800.0   Jan    130.0        both
1    Lexus  150.0   Jan      NaN   left_only
2     Audi  210.0   Feb      NaN   left_only
3  Mustang   90.0   Mar      NaN   left_only
4  Bentley  110.0   Feb      NaN   left_only
5   Jaguar   90.0   Jan      NaN   left_only
6     Tata    NaN   Jan    150.0  right_only
7   Maruti    NaN   Mar    110.0  right_only
8     Audi    NaN   Mar    250.0  right_only
```

Selecting the units columns:

```
units = joined.filter(regex="^Units", axis=1)

>> units

   Units  Units_y
0  800.0    130.0
1  150.0      NaN
2  210.0      NaN
3   90.0      NaN
4  110.0      NaN
5   90.0      NaN
6    NaN    150.0
7    NaN    110.0
8    NaN    250.0
```

Then, since you want the results on the `left` to take precedence, you could fill the `Nan` in the horizontal direction, so if there are any values on `Units` (the value coming from the left), they will be preserved:

```
 filled_units = units.fillna(axis=1, method='bfill')

 >> filled_units

   Units  Units_y
0  800.0    130.0
1  150.0      NaN
2  210.0      NaN
3   90.0      NaN
4  110.0      NaN
5   90.0      NaN
6  150.0    150.0
7  110.0    110.0
8  250.0    250.0
```

Finally, we can slice filled_units and combine it with the values for `Car` and `Month` in `joined`:

```
pd.concat([joined[['Car', 'Month']], filled_units["Units"]], axis=1)

       Car Month  Units
0      BMW   Jan  800.0
1    Lexus   Jan  150.0
2     Audi   Feb  210.0
3  Mustang   Mar   90.0
4  Bentley   Feb  110.0
5   Jaguar   Jan   90.0
6     Tata   Jan  150.0
7   Maruti   Mar  110.0
8     Audi   Mar  250.0
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Works like charm. Thanks a lot Mabel

Comment: Thanks! Could you mark the issue as solved by accepting the answer? @Kashyap